# middleware is not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have this code:

```js
exports.get_transducer_edit = (req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        Transducer.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundTransducer) => {
            if(err){
                res.redirect('/en/dashboard');
            } else {
                res.render('dashboard/transducer_edit-dashboard', {transducer: foundTransducer});
            }
        });
    }else{
        req.flash('error','You need to log in to do that');
        res.redirect('/dashboard/login');
    }
};
```

it runs with no problem, but then when I created a middleware in middleware/index.js:

```js
var middlewareObj = {};

middlewareObj.isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated() ) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/dashboard/login');
};

module.exports = middlewareObj;
```

I called it inside this code:

```js
const middleware = require('../middleware');
const Transducer = require('../models/productTransducers');



exports.get_transducer_edit =  middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        Transducer.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundTransducer) => {
            if(err){
                res.redirect('/en/dashboard');
            } else {
                res.render('dashboard/transducer_edit-dashboard', {transducer: foundTransducer});
            }
        });
    
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help...

Comment: How could this syntax work? `exports.get_transducer_edit = middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {`

Comment: It doesn't, I was wrong and I just solved it. 
this is my controller. I have declared the route like: 

router.get('/en/dashboard/products/transducers/:id/edit', transducer_controller.get_transducer_edit);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just solved.

I called the middleware in my route:

router.get('/en/dashboard/products/transducers/:id/edit', middleware.isLoggedIn, transducer_controller.get_transducer_edit);

I was trying to call it in my controller like:

exports.get_transducer_edit =  middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
...

wrong!

Thanks again.